# Using aircrack on Windows to Crack my WPA

Tags: security, wpa, aircrack-ng

I'm new to hacking and security in general.  I wanted to learn a few things so I'm trying to break into my Wifi which is using WPA security.  I've been googling and trying to find a way to do that for windows.  What I found that has been helpful is this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TAbS_-uqhJQ

I've downloaded an older aircrack version (aircrack-ng-1.0-rc3-win) and Comm for Wifi like in the video.  I ran the Comm for Wifi and I have packets that have the handshake protocol like this:

```
EAPOL-Key(4-Way Handshake Me...
```

When I insert the packet log into the aircrack GUI along with my wordlist.  I get an error saying there no handshakes when very clearly in the log there are several handshakes.  I used a .pcap file from the aircrack website (along with the same password list) and aircrack works fine with that .pcap file.  I've compared their .pcap file with mine and I don't see a difference between them besides the obvious ESSID's and BSSID's and other small details but it looks like the same type of handshake packets are there.

I'm very new to this and I understand that probably Windows is not the best OS for hacking but I feel like I'm pretty close.  Does anybody have any suggestions as to what to do next?  Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: Why exactly are you intentionally using an older version of aircrack? In addition, there are [much better tutorials](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=cracking_wpa) out there.

Comment: Why are you even using windows? Operating systems like BackBox, BlackBuntu, Kali, Cyborg Hawk, etc are available for such tasks with a great set of pre-installed softwares.

Comment: Sorry I haven't responded in a while.  I finally figured it out by throwing my windows machine in a pit of fire, taking a hammer and smashing it then cleaning it up and installing the operating systems that 7_R3x said to use (ended up using Kali).  LOL.  @F.StephenQ The reason  that I used an older version of Aircrack was the newer version required me to install my own DLL files for my computer, which I did not know how to do.  So I tried using an older version that didn't require that.  Anyway thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i prefer you to use kali 2.0 for cracking!

basically wpa cracking steps are

1. switching your wifi adapter to monitor mode.
2. locking a base network(to be attacked).
3. listing the clients connected to it.
   (/ in wpa, packets doesnt contain any relevant data)
   4.for cracking, we have to disconnect a client for few milliseconds ,forcing to reconnect by sending hand shake packets.
4. we have to capture above packets, compare with a wordlist.

Note: wpa cracking is hideous task, if we have no idea of password(its length,characters used)!! it could take several days to crack!!!.. 
u can test it to crack your own network